# Message app in BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am developing one message app which should get the messages from native message application and want to store it in my app's database .

I tried to refer official docs but not getting how to do this ?
 Can anyone tell me the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to access the data through the BB 10 NDK's system using the `MessageService` class. At least this is the closest i could think of if i understood your demands. See https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/pim/messages.html